# C# threading for file uploader

Tags: c#, multithreading

I'm working with c# winform
I have a list of files .With a loop I need to upload all the files (5000 images ) to another server how can I implement it with multithreading
And another point how can I know when one thread is finished and then use it for the next file waiting to be uploaded do I need to use monitor class?

Answer (score 2):

You can use PLINQ for that:

```
IEnumerable<string> yourFiles = new[]{ "C:\\file.txt", "D:\\data.dat" };
int numberOfThreads = 10;

yourFiles.AsParallel().WithDegreeOfParallelism(numberOfThreads).ForAll(UploadFile);

private static void UploadFile(string file)
{
   // do the actual uploading
}
```

Comment: You will need atleast .NET 4

Comment: Yes, indeed. It does need a version of .NET that is not older than **2010**. I didn't think this is important in **2015**.

Comment: I just added the comment as a note. You will be surprised how many enterprise applications still use .NET 2 or 3.5

Answer (score 2):

Maybe Parallel.For is something for you. It is easy to use. You know when a thread is finished because you can add some variable into the end of your method in the another thread. Something like ManualResetEvent. I think Parallel.For is the fasted to implement. You can use a thread pool aswell. Read trough the microsoft websites.

[Parallel.For](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.threading.tasks.parallel.for%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (.NET 4)
`For(Int32, Int32, Action<Int32>)`
[ThreadPool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/3dasc8as.aspx) (.NET 2)
`ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(waitCallback)`